# How can I force distutils.dir_util.copy_tree function to keep going on error?

Tags: python-3.x, distutils

I have the following function which is meant to copy directories from one point to another. However, if it encounters an error it just stops. I would like it to keep going and copy the next file. Can't find anything online and the info on the function is extremely scarce.

Anyone has any clue?

```
def copyFilesAccross(source, destination, upd, file):
    lg.set_verbosity(lg.INFO)
    lg.set_threshold(lg.INFO)
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    log(0, "copyFilesAccross: Copying files ...", file)
    try:
        dir_util.copy_tree(source, destination, update=upd, verbose=1)
        log(0, "copyFilesAccross: Operation has completed successfully in: " + str(datetime.datetime.now() - startTime),
            file)
    except OSError as e:
        log(1, "copyFileAccross: Failed to copy from " + source + " to " + destination + " with error: " + e, file)
    except dir_util.DistutilsFileError as e:
        log(1, "copyFileAccross: Failed to copy from " + source + " to " + destination + " with error: " + str(e), file)
```

Comment: What error you are facing

Comment: Use [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree). Pass a `copy_function` that ignores errors.

Comment: @ZainArshad I have a file like Aux.js that can't be copied across.

Comment: @phd hey. I need to copy directories though. I point to src and dest and it fails on one of the files. If I try to handle in the dir_util.DistutilsFileError it still stops but I'd like it to continue with he next file rather than throwing me out.

Comment: `shutil.copytree` copies tree, i.e. a hierarchy of directories and files.

Comment: well when I asked what's the best way to copy directories everyone said dir_util. now when I am asking how to bypass an issue in this procedure everyone is recommending shutil